# Elements overlaying another making it disappear

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, autolayout

Pitures makes a 1000 words:

This is how it looks in storyboard (IB):

[image]

And in simulator:

[image]

So I was working with this and it was working fine, until I started applying constraints. Then suddenly my arrow disappeared. Took me a good 20 minutes to figure out it had decided to hide behind my button. My view hierarchy implies that the arrow is still drawn after the button, so I don't know why it is hiding like that (also because it was working correctly before constraints added). How do I fix this in IB and/or programmatically?

Comment: Can you post the constraints as well?

Comment: How could the constraints cause this ever. In fact I just "lowered" the constraint to bottomspace so its obvious its hiding behind the button. If I pull the element to another place and back (in the view hierarchy) it will show again. I think it has happened before to me, and it is really annoying, because it shouldn't go hiding all of a sudden I feel. (Anyway, I have constraints bottom space to superview and trailing space to superview, standard constraints)

Comment: This is the same problem, I am facing with Xcode 6.1 update. I think, it is some kind of bug and make things more messy. To avoid this, just use constraint with every element. To update a element, remove the constraint and after updating constraint it again.